# How to handle loading/spinners in container elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out the best way to indicate loading in react between container and presentational elements. Do folks generally avoid any view related items in container elements or do they make an exception for spinner-type elements?

Comment: Probably the best way is to have the view know about how to indicate that it's loading, and pass an isLoading flag to it as a prop. Different views can indicate loading in different ways, and the isLoading flag can often be a part of your app state, and come from redux or something. But it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a matter of preference, I render content in container elements as needed. A loading spinner is no exception. That being said, if you're intending to put a spinner on the whole page then personally the container is a fine spot for this. If you intend to put a spinner over a form or some content region I'd stick to your presentational component for that.